# Laravel - Sending customized Bugsnag error reports based on exception type?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, reporting-services, error-handling

I have a Laravel 7 app that uses a 3rd party PHP package to integrate with a service (Convirza). I bootstrapped and bound the service into the container via my own service provider `App\Providers\ConvirzaServiceProvider`. My problem is that I need to send error logs from the service to Bugsnag (error reporting service)... and depending on the Exception thrown from the service, I need to add metadata to the report. I do NOT want to filter exceptions from the base `App\Exceptions\Handler` class because I want everything to be wrapped into the Service Provider.

For example, when the `Skidaatl\Convirza\Exceptions\BadRequestException` gets thrown, I want to add the request parameters as metadata to the report. Another example would be if the `Skidaatl\Convirza\Exceptions\InvalidTokenException` gets thrown, I want to add the token as metadata to my report.

I would rather not add a try/catch block every time I call the service. How would I go about this?

Here is my Service Provider:

```
class ConvirzaServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->commands([
                Commands\UpdateCampaignsCommand::class,
                Commands\UpdateGroupsCommand::class,
                Commands\GenerateReportsCommand::class
            ]);
        }

        $this->app['events']->subscribe(EventHandler::class);
    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes.php');

        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/database/migrations');

        $this->app->singleton('convirza', function(Container $app) {
            $config = config('convirza.client');
            $config = Config::create($config);
            return new Convirza($config);
        });

        $this->app->bind(ReportBuilder::class, function(Container $app) {
            return new ReportBuilder($app->get('convirza'));
        });

        $this->app->alias('convirza', Convirza::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Bugsnag's [registerCallback](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/laravel/customizing-error-reports/#adding-callbacks) to inspect the report and add metadata based on specific parameters of the report.

For example, you can get the [context](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/laravel/customizing-error-reports/#getcontext) of your exception and even the [stacktrace](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/laravel/customizing-error-reports/#getstacktrace) information. Additionally, you can access the [originalError](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/laravel/customizing-error-reports/#originalerror) to get information including the error message. Using that, you can create logic in a callback to add metadata.

E.g.

```
public function boot()
{
    Bugsnag::registerCallback(function ($report) {
        $stacktrace = $report->getStacktrace();
        $frames = &$stacktrace->getFrames();

        // Adds metadata for `log_error` frame if present
        if ($frames[0]['method'] == 'log_error') {
            $report->setMetaData([
            'account' => [
                'token' => '12345',
            ]
        }
    ]);
}
```